# How to solve this system of differential equations in matlab?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

My task is to model a certain physical problem and use matlab to solve it's differential equations. I made the model but it seems far more complex than what I've learned so far so I have no idea how to solve this.

The black color means it's a constant

[image: The equations]

Answer (score 0):

**I assume that by "solve" you seek a closed form solution of the form x(t) = ..., z(t) = ...** Unforunately, it's very likely you cannot solve this system of differential equations. Only very specific *canonical* systems actually have a closed-form solution, and they are the most simple (few terms and dependent variables). See [Wikipedia's entry for Ordinary Differential Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation), in particular the section *Summary of exact solutions*.

Nevertheless, the procedure for attempting to solve with Matlab's Symbolic Math Toolbox is described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-single-differential-equation.html).

**If instead you were asking for numerical integration**, then I will give you some pointers, but you must carry out the math:

1. Convert the second order system to a first order system by using a substitution w(t) = dx/dt, allowing you to replace the d2x/dt2 term by dw/dt. [Example here.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-differential-equation-numerically-1.html)
2. Read the documentation for [ode15i](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15i.html) and implement your transformed model as an implicit differential equation system.

N.B. You must supply numerical values for your constants.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am fine with numerical integration. I tried doing the first step but how do I get rid of z and dz/dt in the second equation?

![The equations](https://i.imgur.com/JUGRuir.jpg)

Comment: I don't think you can. You will end up with a system of three equations in three unknowns: x, w and z (and their first derivatives). But it doesn't matter does it? You'll have the numerical solution for all three of them.